# Downloading Thymeleaf template from S3

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, thymeleaf, flying-saucer

I am currently storing and downloading my Thymeleaf templates in S3.

I am using the following function to retrieve the Template from S3:

```
    public String getTemplateFile(String name, File localFile) {

    ObjectMetadata object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(connectionProperties.getBucket(), name), localFile);

    boolean success = localFile.exists() && localFile.canRead();

    return localFile.getPath();

}
```

After doing this the file is successfully downloaded in the desired location.

But when trying to access the file from the FlyingSaucer PDF generator the file doesn't exist, despite it is already downloaded in FILE_LOCATION_PATH. (I can open the file... the file is there but the function doesn't see it)

```
 String xHtmlStringDocument =
            convertHtmlToXhtml(templateEngine
                    .process(FILE_LOCATION_PATH,
                            initializeLetterHtmlTemplateContext(letter)));
```

When I run the program again and again I get the same result. But when I STOP the program and RUN it AGAIN then everything works because the file form the last execution is now recognized by the program.

This sounds to me like an asynchronous function issue.

Does anybody know how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED (following suggestion)**

New function: Same result:
(And the file was created, the Download from S3 was successful)

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: ClassLoader resource "static/templates/template.html" could not be resolved

```
    public String getTemplateFileN(String name, File localFile) throws IOException {
    S3Object fullObject = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        fullObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(connectionProperties.getBucket(), name));

        System.out.println("Content-Type: " + fullObject.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());
        System.out.println("Content: ");
        displayTextInputStream(fullObject.getObjectContent());
        in = fullObject.getObjectContent();
        System.out.println(localFile.toPath());
        Files.copy(in, localFile.toPath());

    }   //then later
    finally {
        // To ensure that the network connection doesn't remain open, close any open input streams.
        if (fullObject != null) {
            fullObject.close();
        }
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    return localFile.getPath();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking javadoc
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest-java.io.File-

I see not method signature `ObjectMetadata getObject(GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest,String file)`

There is

```
ObjectMetadata getObject(GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest,
                                File destinationFile)
```

Where you provide File (not String) as second argument. Make sure the file is not opened for write before you try reading it!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I followed your first suggestion but got the same result.
I also updated the question with the method signature.